# wordpress media library description column

Tags: php, functions

I have added a code to show a description column on media libray on wordpress,
below is the code:

```
function column_id($columns) {
    $columns['description'] = __('Description');
    return $columns;
} 
add_filter( 'manage_media_columns', 'column_id' );
 
function column_id_row($columnName, $media_item){
    if($columnName == 'description'){
        $attachment_meta = get_post($media_item);
    echo $attachment_meta->post_content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'column_id_row', 10, 2 );
```

It works perfect with no error, only my concern is whatever I enter under descrition box, all text comes on same line, how can i make sure, second para comes in next line

Comment: anyone has fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [the `nl2br()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) (tested):

```php
function column_id_row( $columnName, $media_item ) {
    if ( 'description' !== $columnName ) {
        return;
    }

    $attachment_meta = get_post( $media_item );
    echo nl2br( $attachment_meta->post_content );
}
add_filter( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'column_id_row', 10, 2 );
```